# Perl - Ratio of homogeneous areas of an image

Tags: perl, image-processing

I would like to check whether an image has a lot of homogeneous areas. Therefore I would like to get some kind of value of an image that declares a ratio for images depending on the amount/size of homogeneous areas (e.g. that value could have a range from 0 to 5).

Instead of a value there could be some kind of classification as well.

[many homogeneous areas -> value/class 5  ; few homogeneous areas -> value/class 0]

I would like to do that in perl. Is there a package/function or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want seems to be an area of image processing research which I am not familiar with. However, [GraphicsMagick's mogrify utility](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/mogrify.html) has a [-segment option](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/mogrify.html#mog-segm):

> Use `-segment` to segment an image by analyzing the histograms of the color components and identifying units that are homogeneous with the fuzzy c-means technique. The scale-space filter analyzes the histograms of the three color components of the image and identifies a set of classes. The extents of each class is used to coarsely segment the image with thresholding. The color associated with each class is determined by the mean color of all pixels within the extents of a particular class. Finally, any unclassified pixels are assigned to the closest class with the fuzzy c-means technique.

I don't know if this is any use to you. You might have to hit the library on this one, and read some research. You do have access to this through [PerlMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/perl.html#manipulate-an-image) as well. However, it does not look like it gives access to the internals, but just produces an image based on parameters.

In my tests (without really understanding what the parameters do), photos turned entirely black, whereas PNG images with large areas of similar colors were reduced to a sort of an average color. Whether you can use that fact to develop a measure is an open question I am not going to investigate ;-)